# PHP array_push() without ordering

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I am using the `array_push()` method to insert ids from my database.

Example:

```
print_r($arr_usr_ids);
Array ( [0] => 34 [1] => 35 [2] => 34 [3] => 37 [4] => 38 [5] => 30 ... ) 

$arr_usrs = array();

foreach($arr_usr_ids as $key => $value) {
if(isset($group_id[1]) && '1'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids[$key]; // 30
 $arr_usrs[] = $numbers;
} else

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '2'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids[$key]; // 34,33
 $arr_usrs[] = $numbers;
} 
...
}
```

and so on...

but array_push is ordering the numbers

```
print_r($arr_usrs);
Array ( [0] => 30 [1] => 33 [2] => 34 [3] => 37 [4] => 38 )
```

the correct result would be 30,34,33,38,37

EDIT this works:

```
$arr_usrs_one = array();
$arr_usrs_two = array();
$arr_usrs_three = array();

foreach($arr_usr_ids as $key => $value) {
if(isset($group_id[1]) && '1'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids[$key]; // 30
 $arr_usrs_one[] = $numbers;
} else

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '2'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids[$key]; // 34,33
 $arr_usrs_two[] = $numbers;
}
... 
}

$result_usrs = array_merge($arr_usrs_one,$arr_usrs_two,$arr_usrs_three);
```

Comment: $array_push is not a function.. do you mean array_push?

Comment: If $array_push is a custom function or closure, then show us the code for that

Comment: no its the standard "PHP Array Function -> array_push" http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: If it's the standard function, then what is the datatype for  $arr_usr_ids, and how are you getting what looks like a comma-separated string value returned when you show your print_r result. What else are you doing to $arr_usrs?

Comment: this would be hard to explain the code comes from my typo3 extension and would be out of the focus of this question...i try another way with array_merge. I put in every "if" a unique array name and use the array_merge at the end to put all together, so i get my right order. I know this is not the best way but it works.

Comment: @MarkBaker datatype for $arr_usr_ids is tinytext and with the result of the numbers i select users from my database with this order...

Comment: Again, I see your edit still has `__$__array_push()` rather than `array_push()`.... is it really `$array_push` in your code?

Comment: @MarkBaker updated with more details

Comment: Unable to replicate `$arr_usrs = array();
$arr_usr_ids = array('30', '34,33', '38,37');

foreach($arr_usr_ids as $key => $value) {
    $numbers = $arr_usr_ids[$key];
    array_push($arr_usrs,$numbers);
}
$newnumbers = implode(',', $arr_usrs);
var_dump($newnumbers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change from `array_push` to `[]`:

```
$arr_usrs = array();

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '1'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids; // 30
 $arr_usrs[] = $numbers;
}

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '2'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids; // 34,33
 $arr_usrs[] = $numbers;
}
print_r($arr_usrs);
```

Comment: has the same effect as with array_push...instead of this 30,34,33,37,38,35 i get this 30,33,34,35,37,38

Comment: @Jim - array_push does __not__ order.... what are you doing to $arr_usrs to get a comma separated string?

Comment: @MarkBaker simply this $newnumbers = implode(',', $arr_usrs); but this is not important because print_r($arr_usrs); shows me the wrong order :/

Comment: @Jim - can you please edit your original question with the real code that you're using; because it also still has $array_push() rather than array_push(), and no indication of the loop that you're using, or where $arr_usr_ids comes from.... just enough of the code to allow us to recreate the problem

Answer (score 0):

`$array_push` refers to a variable.

You properly mean [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
array_push($array, $value);
```

Witch is equal to:

```
$array[] = $value;
```

**Docs:**

> **array_push()** treats *array* as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of *array*. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed. Has the same effect as:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array[] = $var;
> ?>
> ```
>
> repeated for each var.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @Jon Yes, I think so. Pretty sure that OP just missed that one.

Comment: Try calling `array_push` yourself. You will see that it does not reorder anything.

Comment: @Jon Thats also what OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

**`array_push`** is a function. PF the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
$arr_usrs = array();

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '1'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids; // 30
 array_push($arr_usrs,$numbers);
}

if(isset($group_id[1]) && '2'=== $group_id[0]) {
 $numbers = $arr_usr_ids; // 34,33
 array_push($arr_usrs,$numbers);
}
```